# Simulate a USB Device for Automation

Tags: linux, kernel, driver, simulation, libusb

I have to simulate a USB Device for automation and testing purposes (in Linux). Original driver/application for this device uses “libusb” to communicate with it.

I don’t have much experience in Linux and Simulation, after some searching I have understood that I need to write a kernel level driver and an application in user-space to simulate that device. Is this right? If Yes, How can this be done?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Another option might be to use virtualisation software with USB support (such as VirtualBox or Qemu) and write a plugin for that which emulates the USB device for the guest system. (this might be easier)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally implemented it by modifying "libusb", modified it to send and receive usb transfers from message queue instead of usbfs. Programmed my simulator to create libsub type transfers and send/receive them using message queues as well.

Simulator now interprets the incoming transfers and sends it to a command parser, which sends request/message to automation system using sockets in a specific format. Automation system sends it's instruction by sending to command parser using socket. This socket invokes method specific to each request in simulator, Now simulator forms an appropriate transfer structure and passes to device plugin (via libusb) through message queue.

Comment: Would love it if you shared the code for this, I think I will find this useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for would be called a virtual USB device. Currently there is nothing in standard Kernel.Some virtual machine provides USB emulation.e.g. KVM provides USB emulation. There is framework [gadget](http://www.linux-usb.org/gadget/) in which might look for your solution.
Or find something in [Linux USB project](http://www.linux-usb.org/)

Thanks,
Abhijeet

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, looked gadget api before posting this question. Was having difficulty implementing it.

Comment: @gaurav-agrawal, Could you please share some link or sample source code for this question ?

Answer (score 0):

The [usb-vhci](http://sourceforge.net/projects/usb-vhci/) project could be of use if you want the device to be presented to the kernel in the same way as real hardware.